# Cannot authenticate to push or pull repository: remote error: Access denied

Tags: gcloud

My development machine is macOS.

I did initial test for Google Cloud and AppEngine. Did source control upload/download just fine.

Now registered with new email account.

Trying to do the following:
gcloud source repos create my-cool-repo
gcloud source repos clone my-cool-repo

got the error:

fatal: remote error: Access denied to

Any gcloud command gives this error.

I did gcloud init && git config credential.'https://source.developers.google.com'.helper gcloud.sh

But seems my former email account is somewhere in a cache.

I checked in macOS keychain for git and it is not there.

How to make it work?

Comment: I understand you are trying to clone the repository to a different project with a different mail account? Have you checked [Controlling access to repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control) ???

Comment: iMac -I did the following:
1) purchased new domain name
2) purchased new G Suite email account
3) Registered to Google Cloud
4) Created project

Now from command line I can deploy to AppEngine, see results.
Want to use source control. Cannot push, pull, etc. because the error above. 

Tried the same from my MacBook - it is working. 

Conclusion - something is wrong with git credentials on the iMac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a different mail account to access the repository of your previous project (an previous mail account), you need to include the new mail account to the IAM section on Google Cloud Platform.
[Check this documentation!  Controlling access to repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control)